# Jquery Mobile - How to get the data-url in the pagebeforechange event

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-mobile

I would like to get the data-url of the page that triggered the page change. Any ideas?

```
$(document).bind("pagebeforechange", function ( event , data) {
    // get the data-url of the link that triggered the page change
});
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can get the page from which the user is coming within the `data` object:

```
$(document).bind("pagebeforechange", function ( event , data ) {
    console.log(data.options.fromPage.attr('data-url'));
});​
```

Note that since you are binding to the `document` element rather than a single `data-role="page"` element that this will fire twice for each page-change, once for the `fromPage` and once for the `toPage`. The data passed into the event handler for each page's event will be the same as the data for the other page.

Here is a demo: http://jsfiddle.net/Atfrf/2/

Comment: It does fire twice but on the 2nd time there is no toPage. If you want the current page you can at anytime do: $.mobile.activePage.attr('data-url')

Answer (score 2):

The attr method is not work at some browsers, so you'd better to use the jqmData method.
The jqmData can work at any namespace.

`$(document).bind("pagebeforechange", function ( event , data ) {
    console.log(data.toPage.jqmData('url'));
});​`

Answer (score 0):

Why can't you do `$(this).parent('div[data-role|="page"]').attr('data-url')`

Comment: Currently the OP is binding to the `document` element, so `this` will refer to the `document` element. If you bound to something like `[data-role="page"]` then you could use `this`, but since this event fires on both pages, you'll get both pages being equal to `this` in their own event handlers.